# Mailpoet(WP) Newsletter images not showing in Gmail client

Tags: gmail, cloudflare, web-application-firewall, google-cdn

I have a website which is designed in WordPress and is using Cloudflare (with proxy enabled).

In newsletter we use article published on the website and use same SRC of image example: https:example.com/images/article.jpg these images dont show in Gmail when CF proxy is enabled.

I have not found any configuration in CF to allow this for some reason Gmail block these images while images show properly on all other clients.

Lot of similar issue reported on cloudflare forum however we no proper solution only option user do is by disabling CF proxy which means you are compromising website security as it also disable firewall.

Anyone point or configuration for this is appreciated